# Web development software

Tags: web-services

Except from HTMLpad and Dreamweaver, what software is best to use when developing websites? I tried to find the one that code academy uses, but unfortunately, i cannot find something like that. I would like to have something which automatically indents and that it automatically tells you if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptana Studio 3 is a useful IDE (Integrated Development Environment) based off of Eclipse to use.
http://www.aptana.com/

If you are into paid IDE's then WebStorm/PhpStorm/RubyMine may not be a bad choice, especially if you also work with Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA
http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

These may catch syntax errors and help you with formatting, but as with most IDE's it won't catch any logic errors.

I personally use Sublime Text as it handles formatting and does not carry any extra bloat as HTML/CSS and JavaScript are relatively simple languages. It does not do error checking.

Comment: Thanks. Will try those one out.

Comment: No problem. I'm new here too, but if this works for it would be great to have this answer selected. Would help anyone browsing by, not to mention you and I.
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers